# excel vba code to get info from a form on a remote website in ie, and then print that info on worksheet isn't working?

Tags: excel, vba

Can you guys reading this please try my code and see if it works for you?  It isn't entering a number on my worksheet but it worked for someone else.  I have the code in a regular module (not class module, not worksheet module, etc.) in VBA in Excel 2010.

First it should open IE and go to the webpage below.  Then the code should enter the number 2688 (or some other 4-digit number) in cell A20 on the Active WorkSheet.

Should prodID be dimmed as an object?  And does it need object explicit at the top?  or to be in a different type of module?  Could something be wrong with my settings?  Or why isn't it working for me?

```
Sub work_damit()
Dim ieApp As Object
Dim URL As String
Dim prodID As Object
    URL = "http://www.craft-e-corner.com/p-2688-new-testament-cricut-cartridge.aspx"
    Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ieApp
        .Navigate URL
        .Visible = True

 Label1:
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
On Error GoTo errorHandler:

        Set prodID = .document.getElementByID("ProductID")
        Range("A20").Value = prodID.Value
        .Quit
    End With

Exit Sub
errorHandler:
If Err.Number <> 462 Then
GoTo Label1:
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works perfect for me. What i am thinking is, does your broswer loads with that time period?. if not you might get an error.

Istead of using

```
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
```

use

```
Do  While ieApp.Busy
     DoEvents
Loop
```

Comment: Run-time error -- Method 'Busy' of object 'IWebbrowser2' failed ---  I have always gotten error messages when I try to use busystate or readystate in any vba code.

Comment: Which version of Internet explorer are you using.

Comment: Looks it's becuase of Internet Explorer 7. It doesn't have the property Busy or Ready state. Updagrade the internet version. It will work fine.

Comment: "upgrade the internet version" Can you please explain more?  Do you mean download internet explorer 8 and then I won't have busystate/readystate problems?

Comment: Yes. Download the internet Explorer 8 or any new version. Then you shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @Nitheen. that is incorrect. I have been using readystate with IE since 2004 or so. My original code above (which worked for me) is run in IE7

Comment: I have downloaded and installed ie8.  The codes are working now with busy and ready!

Answer (score 1):

You are relying on a set time for the web page to load, if it hasn't loaded in 10 seconds the code diverts to the errorhandler.

**Updated code**

This version uses `xmlhttp` to get the data

```
   Public Sub SidsCode()
'http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_26686033.html
    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim objxmlhttp As Object
    Dim strURL

    On Error GoTo errhandler
    strURL = "http://www.craft-e-corner.com/p-2688-new-testament-cricut-cartridge.aspx"
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Navigate "about:blank"

    Set objxmlhttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.xmlhttp")
    With objxmlhttp
        .Open "GET", strURL, False
        objxmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        objxmlhttp.send
        If .Status = 200 Then
            objIE.document.write objxmlhttp.responseText
            ActiveSheet.Range("A20").Value = objIE.document.getElementByID("ProductID").Value
        Else
            MsgBox "no reponse from site"
        End If
    End With
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
    Exit Sub

errhandler:
    MsgBox "Code failed on" & vbNewLine & Err.Description
    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Original code**

Instead you can code the readystate of the page like so:

```
    Sub work_damit()
    Dim ieApp As Object
    Dim URL As String
    Dim prodID As Object
    URL = "http://www.craft-e-corner.com/p-2688-new-testament-cricut-cartridge.aspx"
    Set ieApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ieApp
        .Navigate URL
        Do While .readystate <> 4
        DoEvents
        Loop
        Set prodID = .document.getElementByID("ProductID")
        Range("A20").Value = prodID.Value
        .Quit
    End With
    Set ie = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Run-time error -- Automation error --  The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.  In debug the highlighted line is "Do While .readyState <> 4".  I have always gotten error messages when I try to use busystate or readystate in any vba code.

Comment: @user1140067 I have changed the retrieval process to xmlhttp. pls try this

Comment: +1 Dave :) @ User1140067. The above code is the right way to do it. It runs ok in my pc :) Which IE version do you have?

Comment: I accepted the other answer because the ie version was the problem.  But I increased your number on the side because your posts were also very helpful.